# What's the StringBuffer alternative for String.endsWith?

Tags: java, concurrency, stringbuffer

I have been using string in concurrent application and to make the code more optimized,i have to use `StringBuffer` instead of String? But I am confused what is the alternative of `string.endsWith("\\")` for `StringBuffer`. What method of `StringBuffer` should be used for the mentioned purpose?

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer unless you have to as it was replaced with StringBuilder ten years ago.

Comment: @PeterLawrey StringBuilder is not thread safe.In case of concurrent application,do you any alternative for  stringbuffer?

Comment: Can you give me an example of where you would use a StringBuffer in a multi-threaded program.  Note: you can only perform one method at a time in a thread safe manner. e.g. `sb.append("a").append("b").toString()` may release the lock between method calls so it is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *direct API*. You could try try `stringBuffer.lastIndexOf("\\")==stringBuffer.length()-1`

OR

`stringBuffer.charAt(stringBuffer.length()-1)=='\\'`

PS : The above code samples are *untested*.

Comment: Shouldn't you be testing the code and then posting it? :)

Comment: @ChetanKinger - Ideally yes. I was just showing the OP how this could be done.

Comment: Is it OK to compare StringBuffer with ==?

Comment: @AbdullahFarid - Not `StringBuffer`, you are comparing `int` values using `==`. So it is OK

Comment: @LostMind stringBuffer.charAt(stringBuffer.length()-1)=='\\' what about this code.its comparing char with ==

Comment: @AbdullahFarid - In this case we are comparing `char` (primitive) values. So `==` is fine

Comment: The above code will fail, if the string length is 0.
Either with an Exception cause -1 index. Or you return true because lastIndex returns -1 and you compare it with -1 as well.

Comment: @keiki - You can use `length()` to check for length before invoking the my code. I answered what the OP wanted. It is extremely difficult to cover all corner cases when one answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can check last character of `StringBuffer`

```
if(buf.charAt(buf.length()-1)=='\\'){
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String objects are **immutable** - so there is no option to changed/modified object state. Other words you shouldn't worry about a concurrency.
My suggestion: keep using String!

Comment: The question was about optimizing, not worrying about concurrency!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) dependency, `StringUtils.endsWith(sb, s)` is simpler than `sb.lastIndexOf(s)==sb.length()-s.length()` and it works with StringBuilder too.